# Нужно запустить цикл while наоборот

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Возникла такая проблема - нужно ajax запросом выводить при скролле до конца блока с новостями 3 новых актуальных новости. JS часть уже готова, но возникли проблемы с php и sql. Пока что я сделал только выполнение и вывод данных с запроса `SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news_date ASC LIMIT '$num'`. Теперь вопрос - как можно вывести 3 последних строки данных запроса?

Comment: А что именно не получается? Покажи код, пожалуйста (что ты возвращаешь клиенту на ajax-запрос, json/какие-либо данные).

Comment: `ORDER BY news_date ASC` - по возрастанию даты, `ORDER BY news_date DESC` - по убыванию даты.

Comment: Покажите полный код, пожалуйста

Comment: *как можно вывести 3 последних строки данных запроса?* Вариант 1: сортировка в обратном порядке, взять 3 первые, во внешнем запросе пересортировать как надо. Вариант 2: получение общего количества записей и формирование полного LIMIT, включающего не только количество, но и начальное смещение.

Comment: Или как посоветовал @Zufir, либо использованием функции array_slice для среза последних трёх значений (http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-slice.php)

Comment: заголовок какое отношение к вопросу имеет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно изменить сортировку в вашем запросе и будете получать то, что нужно

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY news_date DESC LIMIT '$num'
```

Comment: читайте вопрос внимательнее - *...3 последних строки данных запроса*, т.е. уже сделанного запроса